# RewriteRule doesnt work

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url

I want to convert this url

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category.php?cate=mens
```

to:

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category/cate/mens/
```

I have this rule but it doesnt work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule category/cate/(.*)/ category.php?cate=$1
RewriteRule category/cate/(.*) category.php?cate=$1
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"... You've told us what you want, and that you're not getting that, but you haven't told us what you get instead...

Comment: i'm getting page no found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535520/rewriterule-doesnt-work @JonLin answer my issue and it works, i post here for if somebody need it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /g2g/

RewriteRule ^category/cate/(.+?)/?$ category.php?cate=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /g2g/category\.php\?cate=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /g2g/category/cate/%2?%3 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic backwards:

```
RewriteRule category/cate/(.*)/ category.php?cate=$1
RewriteRule category/cate/(.*) category.php?cate=$1
```

This will attempt to rewrite `category/cate/mens/` into `category.php?cate=mens`

You can't just reverse it though, because RewriteRule can't operate with query strings, so you need to use RewriteCond as well:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     cate=(.*)
RewriteRule /category.php       category/cate/%1
```

Note the use of `%1` to refer to the back-reference in `RewriteCond` (rather than `$1` for a backref in `RewriteRule`)

Comment: i'm trying this,i'll comment

Comment: thanks for the answer, I change the code as you suggested, now i'm getting Not Found in the url [link](http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category/cate/womens)

Comment: Well it appears the rewrite is working, and that page just does not exist...

Comment: Does your original question have the URL's the wrong way around?

Comment: this is the original url [link](http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category.php?cate=mens) and after change my code i type [link](http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category/cate/mens) could you help me to undestard what happen

Comment: Well the original URL is being rewritten to the new one correctly... The new one just doesn't exist. It sounds like you're trying to "mask" the original URL with the new URL, is that right? If so, mod_rewrite can't do that, it tells the browser to make a new request for the new URL, so if the new URL doesn't exist, it will 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cate=(.*)
RewriteRule g2g/category.php g2g/category/cate/%1? [L]
```

This will do exactly what you want. Notice the "?" in RewriteRule stops the query string (?cate=mens) being appended again.